# Do complex conjugates commute?

Tags: integration, complex-numbers, quantum-mechanics

I wasn't sure how to ask this question, but I was wondering whether (this came up in the context of quantum mechanics) the integral $$\int f_m ^* f_ndx=\int f_n ^* f_mdx$$
is in general true. I have a hazy idea from somewhere that it is but can't recall for sure. I know the information will be out there online, but I don't know what to search for.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For complex numbers $a,b$, we have $(a^*b)^* = ab^* = b^*a$. Consequently, we have
$$
\int f_m ^* f_ndx=\int (f_n ^* f_m)^* dx
=\left(\int f_n ^* f_mdx\right)^*.
$$

Comment: Thank you. I don't think (I'm not certain) that answers my question in that it doesn't address whether the expression also = $$\int f_n^* f_m dx$$

Comment: Your expression is the result of an integral, and is in particular a number.  When is a complex number equal to its complex conjugate?

Comment: When it's real?

Comment: Ok, I think I see now. Thank you.